# tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal no module windows 10 tensorflow gpu

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

"tensorflow-cpu" works fine on my device with windows 10.
I was trying to install tensorflow-gpu and after installing it fails to import showing the following error.

> tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal no module

I have installed the following

> CUDA 10.1
>
> Nvidia graphics driver Version 419
>
> CUDnn for CUDA 10.1
>
> VC++ 2015 REDIST

Could anyone say what am i missing here is complete error message.

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your are sure you have **Visual C++ 2015 Redist** installed on your Windows machine then probably it is the version conflict between **CUDA** version and the **Tensorflow** version. Because newer versions have some conflicts and more over tensorflow requires the exact version of CUDA and the CUDnn Library for it to work properly.

The best way to get it configured correctly is using **Anaconda** for installing and configuring tensorflow-gpu as conda will automatically download all the necessary versions of CUDA and CUDnn for the corresponding tensorflow

The problem is that the new Anaconda uses Python 3.7.x by default which is not supported by tensorflow or tensorflow-gpu

So install Anaconda You can download it [here](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/)

Now create a virtual environment using conda with python 3.6.x configured by typing the following in Anaconda Prompt

```
conda create -n yourenvname python=3.6 anaconda
```

Now change switch to your environment by typing in

```
conda activate yourenvname
```

Now Check the python version by using which should show you something like this

```
> python --version
Python 3.6.7 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
```

Now finally install tensorflow-gpu

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu
```

Now open python and try importing tensorflow

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

[image]

Congrats ! You are all set.