# ImportError: cannot import name pywrap_tensorflow (Wrong Directory?)

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, ipython, jupyter

Everything was working fine a few days ago. Recently something unknowingly went wrong and now I can't use tensorflow. I've googled this question and the main answer is that people are running the script in the same directory as tensorflow, however, I don't think this is the case. I could be wrong though. Below is the trace:

```
(MachineLearning)    C:\Users\Rob\Anaconda3\envs\MachineLearning\Scripts\BERT_multilabel_text_classification-master>bert-serving-start -model_dir C:/Temp/uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/ -cpu -num_worker=4 -max_seq_len None -verbose
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\rob\anaconda3\envs\machinelearning\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "c:\users\rob\anaconda3\envs\machinelearning\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\Rob\Anaconda3\envs\MachineLearning\Scripts\BERT_multilabel_text_classification-master\bert-serving-start.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
File "c:\users\rob\anaconda3\envs\machinelearning\lib\site-packages\bert_serving\server\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
_tf_ver_ = check_tf_version()
File "c:\users\rob\anaconda3\envs\machinelearning\lib\site-packages\bert_serving\server\helper.py", line 168, in check_tf_version
import tensorflow as tf
File "C:\Users\Rob\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
File "C:\Users\Rob\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
ImportError: cannot import name 'pywrap_tensorflow'
```

If there's anything else y'all'd like to see please let me know, and if y'all have any suggestions please throw them this way. Can't tell if I'm being dumb or if this is different from the rest lol. Thanks

Comment: Try uninstall and reinstall tensorflow in your env, by doing so if working in Conda you should solve again all dependencies.

Comment: @JohnCalchon, thanks! I had tried your suggestion prior with no difference, however, what did work was deleting all tensorflow files from my computer, and setting up an new env & installing tensorflow. A little radical but it was possible given my setup. Your comment led me to that so much appreciated

Comment: Check below StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55200171/tensorflow-python-pywrap-tensorflow-internal-no-module-windows-10-tensorflow-gpu